# API for live account Tasks (Outlook.com Calendar)

Tags: api, outlook.com

Actually, I've setup my outlook.com account on MS Outlook. I wanted my tasks to be shown on my Windows Phone 7.8 device **by categories**. Tasks are synced with the WP device but as you know there are no categories!

I didn’t find any appropriate way to have my outlook.com task categories on my WP device. So I decided to implement a simple mobile webpage that retrieve my tasks from outlook.com calendar and display them by categories. This way I can have my tasks ordered by categories on my mobile devices.

How can I retrieve my tasks from outlook.com calendar? Is there any API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is an API, however, you have to join the development program which costs $49.

Here's the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx#cal_cs

Answer (score 1):

Outlook.com does not support programmatic access to tasks at this point.

The unified O365 and Outlook.com APIs were announced on August 12 2015.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/08/12/unified-outlook-apis-for-office-365-amp-outlook-com-are-here.aspx .

Full API specs are available at https://dev.outlook.com/ . As of this writing you will find APIs for Mail, Calendar, Contact, Notifications, and Photos.

I know this isn't satisfactory.

The best place to give feedback would be at http://appsforoutlook.uservoice.com/forums/284422-other .